# Finding duplicates in MYSQL table where data is in "title" -> "value" columns and other data in other related table

Tags: mysql, duplicates, multiple-tables

Given I know the basics of MYSQL I would appreciate help with the following:

> ## table -> subrecords schema
>
> #### id     | record |  element |   title | name |  type |  value

The table stores data submitted via a web form.
Each row is one field
the "record" is the field that identifies each unique submitted form, the title of the form is stored in another table:

> ## table -> records schema
>
> #### id |   submitted | form |  title | name

I need to find all users (by email) that submitted the same form more than once:

(Thanks to the kind help of @gwc)

- all email addresses (subrecords.value where subrecords.title = 'email')
- that have more than one of the same form submitted (identified by "string" record.title = "form-name").
- subrecords.record = record.id is needed simply to join the tables (each form submission is unique and generates a new record.id thus not helpful to identify neither the user nor the form).
- records.form is a foreign key = forms.id

Thank you

Comment: `GROUP BY` email (which isn't in your columns unfortunately) and then `COUNT(*) as submits`.  Wrap it up with `HAVING submits > 1`.  (Oh, `WHERE title='email' GROUP BY value` might work).

Comment: How do you know which form (records table row) a given field (subrecords table row) is related to? Maybe answered my own question. Is it subrecords.record = records.id?

Comment: @gwc I assumed record -> record.id

Comment: @gwc yes, subrecords.record = record.id

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a sql pro or anything but I have no idea what is going on in your query :)

But give this a go.

EDITED:

```
SELECT sr.Value
    , COUNT( sr.* )
FROM Subrecords sr
    JOIN Records r
       ON sr.record = r.id
      AND r.Title = 'form_name' 
WHERE sr.Title = 'email'
GROUP BY sr.Value
HAVING COUNT( sr.* ) > 1
```

I can't fully understand what is going on with your tables, so if there is more than 1 form this is not going to get what you want.

Comment: Just remember the `WHERE title = 'email'`.  When `title = 'dogsname'` would muddy the waters otherwise.

Comment: see my edit.  I'm not sure what the foreign key is in subrecords, just change accordingly.

Comment: @CrckrJack #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '* ) FROM subrecords sr JOIN records r ' at line 2

Comment: try removing the aliases, or take a look at @gwc's answer. his looks better :)

Comment: @CrckrJack gwc first query returns empty result which is impossible since it should look for all duplicate emails, and about 95% of the users has submitted multiple emails, I also tried your query removing aliases and using full table names, still syntax error at line 2

Answer (score 0):

**Updated for additional requirements**

```
SELECT value     as email
      ,record
      ,COUNT(*)  as form_count
  FROM subrecords
 WHERE title = 'email'
   AND record IN (SELECT id
                    FROM records
                   WHERE name = '{$form_name}'
                 )
 GROUP BY value
         ,record
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

**Original**

Assuming the relationship between subrecords and records is subrecords.record = records.id:

```
SELECT s.value   as email
      ,r.id
      ,r.title
      ,COUNT(*)  as form_count
  FROM records r
  JOIN subrecords s
    ON s.record = r.id
   AND s.title = 'email'
 GROUP BY s.value
         ,r.id
         ,r.title
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

will tell you which users (by email) have submitted which forms (by id and title) more than once and how many times in total.

If all you need is the form's ID, then this should do it:

```
SELECT value     as email
      ,record
      ,COUNT(*)  as form_count
  FROM subrecords
 WHERE title = 'email'
 GROUP BY value
         ,record
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: Just to further clarify I need to filter one specific form name and find all users who submitted this form more than once (duplicate email) your first query returns empty result (something is not correct as this is not possible) the second query misses the point as it needs to be joined to record table in order to filter by form.

Comment: neither of the 2 query return any result, I appreciate your efforts, however there is something wrong. Let me know any suggestion

Comment: Ok. so, let's get specific "form name" means record.title or record.form or record.name or something else? I'll assume record.name. So if I understand correctly, you want to know all email addresses (subrecords.value where subrecords.title = 'email') that have more than one subrecords.record = record.id for a specified (assume by you) record.name?

Comment: Also, it would help greatly if you could provide sample data and/or set up a sqlfiddle ( http://sqlfiddle.com/ ) playground.

Comment: I was assuming that the record table represented a single form (as in a template) that all users who submit the same form would reference. now, I'm starting to wonder if there can be many rows in the record table with the same value in the 'form' column. and record.form is actually a foreign key to another table that defines the actual forms to be filled out. Is this on the right track? If so, then is definitely changes the answer.

Comment: Apologies if I was not clear and thank you again for your great help!! With 1 minor correction here is what I need: all email addresses (subrecords.value where subrecords.title = 'email') that have more than one of the same form submitted (record.title = "form-name"). subrecords.record = record.id is needed simply to join the tables (each form submission is unique and generates a new record.id). then yes records.form is a foreign key = forms.id. I just tested after changing this bit to `WHERE title = 'name of the form'` and still zero result. If easier I can get data, I just need to obscure it

Comment: Hello @gwc I would really appreciate any further help if you have any time. Thank you so much.